# Float an Image to the Right With No Text Wrapping

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/calebp/ksnmggL5/light/

I am having some difficulty with a web page I am trying to make. In the linked example, I have the images exactly where I want them (the larger one aligned right and the banner aligned right but to the left of it). The problem I have is that I want the paragraph below the banner image. How can I get it to go entirely below it, instead of a random 'the' floating off in the distance?

```
<div style="width: 920px;">
<div style="clear: both; text-align: left;">
<a href="largeimage.png"><img border="0" src="largeimage.png"  style="float: right; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-left: .75em;"/></a>
<img border="0" src="banner.png" style="clear: left; float: right; margin-bottom: 1em;"/>
<p>THE PARAGRAPH</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is what I want it to look like, but without the fixed width: 
https://jsfiddle.net/calebp/ksnmggL5/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can put the banner and the paragraph-text in one div and make the width the same as the banner.

Comment: I had thought about this, but the banner is not as wide as the space. It ends up leaving space to the left of the paragraph. Also, the paragraph needs to be able to change width, so it will be readable on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You needed some architectural bliss first. I took all your inline styles and put them in classes. You need classes so you can manipulate your HTML better. Stay away from inline styling. Then all you have to do is wrap your paragraph in a div and give it the following code:

```
    .row{
      float:left;
      width:33%;
    }

    .paragraph {
      float:left;
      width:66%;
      margin-left:5px;
    }
```

p.s. I suggest you learn how to use an HTML/CSS responsive framework such as Bootstrap. It will save you all this headaches as long as you use the right classes.

Here is your fixed [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGRJZm)

Comment: Thanks, but this placed the text below both images. I want it below the banner, but to the right of the larger image.

Comment: ok. which one is the banner and which one is the image. They are both images. This is why classes are important. You can use them descripttively by using naming conventions.

Comment: Sorry. By banner, I mean the skinnier one to the left that is just a graphic. The image I refer to is the photo. Oh, and I meant left in the previous comment and not right.

Comment: ok, my answer concept still applies. Wrap the elements in divs. I edited my jfiddle. If it's backwards, all you have to do is place the divs in the order you want them

Comment: so, banner (floated to the left) paragraph below it, and then image below that floated to the right?

Comment: oh I see, the text is right of the image. Hold on. let me edit

Comment: What I mean is what this paragraph looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/calebp/ksnmggL5/5/    But without the fixed width.

Comment: Check now... and for future reference, use CODE PEN. It's way better than JFiddle. ;). I edited my link in my answer

Comment: Sorry, for my poor explanations. What I mean is what this paragraph looks like: jsfiddle.net/calebp/ksnmggL5/5 But without the fixed width. Basically, just making it so that the entire paragraph is together below the graphical banner.

Answer (score 0):

Use the basics of css layout.

First make a structure of blocks with selectors. Then add css to each selector.
So I think your HTML structure should be like this.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="topBanner">
        <img />
        <div id="text">
            <p>THE PARAGRAPH</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightBanner">
        <a href="image.png"><img /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add css styles

```
#container {
  width:187%;
}
#topBanner{
  width: 50%;
  float:left
}
#rightBanner{
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
#text{
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Try this example on jsFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6bf80ue/)